# Pass Rails variable from controller to JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Problem description:**

I have a view with set of links:

```
<% @feeds.each do |f| %>                
  <div class="feed">
    <span class="feed_counts"> <%= f.display_counts %> </span>
    <%= link_to "refresh", { :controller => 'Feeds', :action => "refresh_feed", :feed_id => f.id}, :remote => true, :class => 'refresh_feed_link' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Users click on the link and launch next controller method:

```
def refresh_feed
  @feed = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
  @feed.parse
end
```

Now I want to change the content of the corresponding span-element to @feed.total_count value.

**My attempts:**

Well, as I know there is a two way's to do it without reloading whole the page:

*Way 1:*

I can include js in my layout:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/partial_js' %>
```

and use this code in the partial_js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {

    $('.refresh_feed_link').bind('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.feed').find('span.feed_counts').text('woo');
    });
 });
</script>
```

In this case I have '$(this)' and I can find the corresponding 'span' element. But I don't have any possibility to get my @feed varible value.

*Way 2:*

I can add

```
respond_to do | format |  
  format.js {render :layout => false}  
end
```

to my controller and create refresh_feed.js.erb file.  In this JS file I can use my variable as <% @feed.total_count %>, but I don't know which of my multiple links was clicked.  In the other words the $(this) variable in this file will be (window) and I cannot find corresponding span-element.

**Question:**

Is there any way to get what I want ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Using the wayds that you described, here's a simple solution for the "which link was clicked" problem: [dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id).

1) Make a partial: app/views/feeds/_feed.html.erb

```
<%= div_for feed do %>
  <span class="feed_counts"> <%= feed.display_counts %> </span>
  <%= link_to "refresh", { :controller => 'Feeds', :action => "refresh_feed", :feed_id => feed.id}, :remote => true, :class => 'refresh_feed_link' %>
<% end %>
```

2) In your view:

```
<%= render @feeds %>
```

3) In your refresh_feed.js.erb file:

```
$('<%= dom_id(@feed) %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript( render @feed ) %>');
```

There's another way that I personally like better, but it will take a me a little while to write it up, so I'll leave this for you here while I write up the other way.

---

**Second Way**

Here's how I do it, using CoffeeScript and HAML because they're easier to type. You can just convert this to plain JS and ERB and it will work the same.

I would setup my routes like so:

```
resources :feeds do
  get "refresh_feed", :on => :member
```

Assuming you've got a "feed" partial, `app/views/feeds/_feed.html.haml`:

```
= div_for feed, :class => 'feed_widget' do
  %span.feed_counts= f.display_counts
  = link_to "Refresh", refresh_feed_path(f), :class => 'refresh_link'
```

In any view:

```
= render @feeds

// or, more explicit:

= render :partial => 'feed/feeds', :collection => @feeds, :as => :feed
```

Now, in `app/assets/javascripts/feeds.js.coffee`

```
# Global Scope for CoffeesScript, ignore for JS
root = exports ? this

# Check page if there are feed widgets on it and initialize a handler for each one.
jQuery ->
  if $('div.feed_widget').length
    $('div.feed_widget').each ->
      new FeedWidget $(this)

root.FeedWidget = (container) ->
  @container = container
  @refresh_link = @container.find('a.refresh_link')
  @feed_counts = @container.find('span.feed_counts')
  this.initialize()

root.FeedWidget.prototype =
  initialize: ->
    self = this
    @feed_counts.click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $.ajax
        type: 'GET'
        url: self.refresh_link.attr 'href'
        dataType: 'json'
        error: (xhr, status, error) ->
          console.log error
          console.log xhr
        success: (data, status, xhr) ->
          self.feed_counts.text data.feed_counts
```

Then in your controller:

```
def refresh_feed
  @feed = Feed.find(params[:id]) #assuming you have a resourceful route to this.
  @feed.parse
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :json => { feed_counts: @feed.counts }, :status => :ok } # use whatever method gets you the feed count here.
  end
end
```

Now you are getting a JSON response that is just the feed count, and you have a single JS listener/handler widget that will automatically show up (and function) and place you render that partial. Cool huh?

Note, the above code is not tested since I don't have your app, so you'll have to refine it for your needs. But ask questions and I'll do my best to answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After 1) and 2) I get the error "undefined local variable or method 'f' for #<#<Class:0x3c2ac00>:0x4303608>", so I have changed '<%= render @feeds %>' to '<%= render :partial => "feed.html.erb", :locals => { :f => @feeds } %>'.  In this case I get the error 'undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class' because @feeds is array of records.

Comment: I accidentally left your local variable as 'f', it should have been 'feed'. I changed it in my expanded answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly I don't need to use each-construction in my view `(<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>)`.  Is it right ?  `<%= render @feeds %>` will call partial for each feed in the `@feeds` automatically ?

Comment: Yes, it will. Thank you very much for your excelent answer. I have known many new things from your reply. But I need a little time test all of them :)

Comment: Yeah, `render @feeds` is just short for `render :partial => 'feed/feeds', :collection => @feeds, :as => feed`. That and `render @feed` (singular) are just built-in rails shortcuts if you follow the standard naming convention. Glad I could help, have fun!

Comment: A little fix : `<% div_for feed do %>` must be `<%= div_for feed do %>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19656/discussion-between-demas-and-andrew)

Comment: One more fix: `$('<%= dom_id(@feed) %>')` must be `$('#<%= dom_id(@feed) %>')`.  And one question: why do I need `'<%= escape_javascript( render @feed ) %>'`? It didn't work for me and I change it by `replaceWith('<%= @feed.display_counts %>')` which works fine.

Comment: Joining chat - for posterity, `render @feed` in a JS template should work as long as `render @feed` works in a normal view, ie if you have a partial named `feeds/feed` that accepts a local object `feed`.